# Hidden field in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a strange issue, where I have a table being populated by info from a database.

When I select from the database, the information comes back exactly as I would expect.

For some reason in my HTML table I have an odd field I can't see the source off.

My table header row:

```
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th><h3>ID</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>First Name</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Last Name</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Odd additional field</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Country</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Room type</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Number</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Checkin Date</h3></th>\n";
echo "<th><h3>Nights</h3></th>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

The field I have called 'Odd additional field appears even if I take it out, it just isn't named.

My code to populate the table:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
echo "<tr url=\"edit.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">\n";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>\n";
echo "<td>" .  $row['firstName'] . "</td>\n";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</h3><td>\n";
echo "<td>" .  $row['country'] . "</td>\n";
echo "<td>" . $row['roomtype'] . "</td>\n";
echo "<td>" . $row['roomnumber'] . "</td>\n";
echo "<td>" . $row['checkin'] . "</td>\n";
echo  "<td>" . $row['nights'] . "</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

The resultant HTML that goes to the browser:

```
<table width = "80%" align="center" id="example">
<tr>
<th><h3>ID</h3></th>
<th><h3>First Name</h3></th>
<th><h3>Last Name</h3></th>
<th><h3>Country</h3></th>
<th><h3>Room type</h3></th>
<th><h3>Number</h3></th>
<th><h3>Checkin Date</h3></th>
<th><h3>Nights</h3></th>
</tr>
<tr url="edit.php?id=1">
<td>1</td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>Schmoe</h3><td>
<td>canada</td>
<td>mdorm</td>
<td></td>
<td>2012-11-16</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Which all seems fine, and yet when viewing in a browser, this is what I see.

[image]

How can I trace this mysterious field?

Comment: Be more specific about the exact query and what database interface you are using (PDO? MySQLi? Custom?). Is your fetch mode set appropriately?

Comment: you have an extra </h3> : `echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</h3><td>\n";`

Comment: Its probably related to this `echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</h3><td>\n"` closing `</h3>`? also there is no need for all thos echos

Comment: Since you're doing zero HTML escaping on your values, what if one of the values has HTML in it and it's throwing off your table?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem - why on earth wouldn't you break out of php to write the html in a sane way? all that echo echo echo is hard to read, hard to maintain and totally unnecessary.

Comment: @KaiQing This is the first time I have programmed anything. The example I was following did it that way, and since the html is populated by a php variable I thought it was necessary. What is the preferred way?

Comment: i posted as an answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</h3><td>\n";`

should be

`echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";`

Answer (score 1):

OP Asked for an example on the preferred way to write html for his example. Please don't treat this as an actual answer to his question:

```
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()): ?>
<tr data-url="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastName']; ?></h3><td>
    <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['roomtype']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['roomnumber']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['checkin']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nights']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here's why this is preferred, though the opinion may vary from person to person:
Maintainability:
if code is easier to read, it is easier to maintain. when you echo html in php you are subject to escaping html, making it more cluttered to read...

```
<?php echo "<div class=\"someclass\">" . $content . "</div>"; ?>
```

effectively the same as:

```
<?php echo '<div class="someclass">' . $content . '</div>'; ?>
```

except that the second example (single quotes is string literal) does not require escaping the double quotes. However, in either case, anyone who has to maintain this would much prefer this:

```
<div class="someclass"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

Because it is cleaner. Why? It just is. Also, many of the editors people use will highlight syntax differently for each language, so that in part makes it easier to read.

There may be cases where echoing html in php makes some sense, but treat it very sparingly. Anyone that reads your code after you will appreciate it.

Side note - you might want to change the html attribute "url" in your example to "data-url" as this is another convention you should use to keep people happy. Custom attributes are supported, but it is not a good idea to just make them up as you go. But if you have to, data- is the standard prefix for custom attributes.